# REGEX: Remove middle of string after certain number of "/"

Tags: r, regex

How do I remove the middle of a string using regex. I have the following url:
https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1347185/000134718517000016/0001347185-17-000016-index.htm/exh1025730032017.xml

but I want it to look like this:

https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1347185/000134718517000016/exh1025730032017.xml

I can get rid of everything after "data/../../"
That last long string of numbers isnt needed

I tried this

```
    sub(sprintf("^((?:[^/]*;){8}).*"),"", URLxml)
```

But it doesnt do anything! Help please!

Comment: How do you define the middle of the URL?

Comment: If this is just one example of many urls you must work with, more information about what changes in each example and what stays the same is needed.

Comment: Well so, nothing changes eh? Will be the same every time, path depth, http ?  Based on what you say, there is not enough information to answer. Oh, but there is 1 answer I see...

Comment: Try this `^(?!mailto:)(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)?(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?:(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})))|localhost)(?::\d{2,5})?(?:\/[^\s]*)?$`

Answer (score 1):

To remove the last but one subpart of the path, you may use

```
x <- "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1347185/000134718517000016/0001347185-17-000016-index.htm/exh1025730032017.xml"
sub("^(.*/).*/(.*)", "\\1\\2", x)
## [1] "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1347185/000134718517000016/exh1025730032017.xml"
```

See the [online R demo](https://ideone.com/cm4sEh) and here is a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GSrivB/1).

**Details**:

- `^` - start of a string
- `(.*/)` - Group 1 (referred to with `\1` from the replacement string) any 0+ chars up to the last but one `/`
- `.*/` - any 0+ chars up to the last `/`
- `(.*)` - Group 2 (referred to with `\2` backreference from the replacement string) any 0+ chars up to the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
a<-'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1347185/000134718517000016/0001347185-17-000016-index.htm/exh1025730032017.xml'

gsub('data/(.+?)/(.+?)/(.+?)/','data/\\1/\\2/',a)
```

so in the url:

data/.../.../..(this is removed)../ ....